# How do I customise product pages in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, storefront

I have created a child theme to work alongside storefront and am struggling to customise the layout of the individual product pages.

Under single-product.php I was expecting to see html markup that I could manipulate but actually what is declared is this:

```
wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
```

With no access to the actual code…

Similarly, with my search bar, I need to add code to the individual product search results. But in search.php the following is declared:

```
get_template_part( 'loop' );
```

Again, forcing me to use JS and CSS to manipulate the appearance as best I can.

Comment: First read [Override WooCommerce templates via the theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) … Then you need to edit  [`content-single-product.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.0/templates/content-single-product.php) related template file or to alter the query arguments through available hooks… For `get_template_part( 'loop' );` is related to Wordpress Loop template…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the `get_template_part()` function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/ and the woocommerce template structure: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

---

With woocommerce you can edit template files in a update-safe way:

1. In the folder of your theme (wp-content/themes/yourtheme) create an empty folder called `woocommerce`.
2. Go to the template directory in the woocommerce plugin (wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates) and copy the file called `content-single-product.php`.
3. Paste the file into your just created folder called `woocommerce` in your theme folder.
4. You can now do your adjustments and keep them, even if the woocommerce plugin gets updated.

---

In your search.php file you are loading a file called `loop.php` which should be in your theme folder (wp-content/themes/yourtheme). Edit this file to do your changes. Maybe there is a subfolder in your theme called `template-parts` or similar, depending on the theme you are using.

Comment: Thanks that's been quite useful, though on the search.php answer im still a bit confused. In loop.php, it seems to get the code using this line: get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );   Where is that pulling the code from? Its a wild goose chase to actually find where i can edit the code